# "Everyone" or "everybody"

Tags: word-choice, one-body

Are the words *everybody* and *everyone* interchangeable?

Comment: I wouldn't use "everybody" in a mortuary.

Answer (score 4):

Either one would work.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whom you are addressing.

- Hi everyone = Hi to each one of you
- Hi everybody = Hi to all of you at once

Comment: I still think "Hi everyone" means the group as one.

Comment: There is no generally understood distinction in meaning like this.

Answer (score 1):

From [LearnersDictionary.com](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/everybody-or-everyone)

> The short answer is, there's not much difference! Both of these words mean "every person," and in dictionaries, the meaning of *everyone* is often given as *everybody*, and vice versa.
>
> However, it's worth mentioning that many people think *everybody* is a little more casual (more informal) than *everyone*. Also, *everybody* is used more often than *everyone* in spoken language, which makes sense if it's more informal. Having said this, it's absolutely fine to use either one. You have a choice.